# JBehave junit test output grouping

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

Currently I'm trying to do some BDD with JBehave and using the "JUnitStory" as follows.

```
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;

public class MyStory extends JUnitStory {
    @Override
    public Configuration configuration() {

        return new MostUsefulConfiguration()
                .useStoryLoader(new MyStoryLoader("src\\main\\resources\\hello.story"));
    }

    @Override
    public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
        return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(), new MySteps());
    }
}
```

My question is even my step file contains multiple scenarios, the junit output is not grouped by the scenario. Could you please advice me how to do this.

My step file is as follows

```
Narrative:
  In order to find items that I would like to purchase
  As a potential buyer
  I want to be able to search for items containing certain words

Scenario: Should list items related to a specified keyword
Given The "XXXX" is initiated as
|Description|Value|Matcher|Verified|
|Value1|Value1|"Value1"|Yes|
|Value2|Value2|"ValueX"|No|
When The "YYYY" submission is invoked as
|Description|Value|Matcher|Verified|
|Value1|Value1|"Value1"|Yes|
|Value2|Value2|"ValueX"|No|
Then The "ZZZZ" should be
|Description|Value|Matcher|Verified|
|Value1|Value1|"Value1"|Yes|
|Value2|Value2|"ValueX"|No|

Scenario: Should be able to filter search results by item type
Given The "XXXX" is initiated as
|Description|Value|Matcher|Verified|
|Value1|Value1|"Value1"|Yes|
|Value2|Value2|"ValueX"|No|
When The "YYYY" submission is invoked as
|Description|Value|Matcher|Verified|
|Value1|Value1|"Value1"|Yes|
|Value2|Value2|"ValueX"|No|
Then The "ZZZZ" should be
|Description|Value|Matcher|Verified|
|Value1|Value1|"Value1"|Yes|
|Value2|Value2|"ValueX"|No|
```

Current result pane is as follows.

[image]

I just want to categorize outputs by scenario

Answer (score 1):

Use JBehave JUnit runner for that purpose: https://github.com/valfirst/jbehave-junit-runner.

The example of output:

[image: JBeahve Junit output example]